# Cordova Plugin Geolocation Timeout on IOS 11

Tags: android, ios, cordova, geolocation, cordova-plugins

I visited all links about this problem and none helped me.

I get the error code 3 (timeout) in response always when execute the method "getCurrentLocation" from "cordova-plugin-geolocation" on IOS .

follow my code:

```
getCurrentPosition() {
 return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      resolve(position);
    }, (error) => {
      reject(error);
    }, {
      timeout: 10000
    });
  }, false);
 });
}
```

I upgraded all plugins and engines and the error persisted. 
Follow my current versions:

- cordova 8.0.0;
- cordova-ios 4.5.4;
- cordova-android 7.0.0;
- cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.0.

Comment: Have you already tried to set maximumAge > 0? Because you might be at an environment where your device can not acquired a new position right after your app is started. So if I were you I would set it at least to 10000 (10 seconds) to tell this plugin that 10 secs old coords are allowed for instance.

Comment: Yes, I already did this test. but still the same error. I noticed that in IOS no permission window appears and nothing is shown about the app in the location permission settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the hardwork, I found the fix. I added the follow keys in "/platform/ios/{project_name}/{project_name}-Info.plist":

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>My app requires constant access to your location, even when the screen is off.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>My app requires constant access to your location, even when the screen is off.</string>
```